# How to create Nginx custom strategy for upstream

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I want to serve multiple versions of my application to my users based on custom logic.

Is it possible to write a custom strategy for nginx to choose which of the entries in `upstream` should be chosen? By default it uses round-robin from what I understand, but I would want to be able to write some program/ function that would let me choose which entry to call.